# Ajax div to refresh on success not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have a DIV which contains how many likes fetching from Mysql database.
I click on button which says like and it will go through ajax function **like(id1)** with parameter.

Ajax use page **likes.php** and does all job adding to database. And it gives out JSON data as feedback with **code** zero if successful. And one if fails.

In success section ajax **_js.code** is one then its already liked. Thus shows us message. But my problem is I cannot refresh DIV likes when code is zero which is success. It either goes to top of the page instead of staying at DIV **likes**.

For information it also appends hash TAG at the end of URL.

Button line, I want like button which should work as **facebook** or other major app does. Without moving page on top. And update like button immediately when clicked.

**My main page**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like" onclick="like(<?php echo $_SESSION["id"];?>);"/>
<div id="likes">
<?php
    $like = 0;
    $conditions = "WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]";
    echo $total = $ll->get_likes($conditions); //displaying how many likes
?>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
function like(id1) {

    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likes.php",
        data: {id: id1 },
        success: function(feedback) {

            var _js = jQuery.parseJSON(feedback); 

            $("#likes").html(_js.message);  //printing message here 
            $("#likes").attr("class", ""); //resetting class of CSS

            if( _js.code == 0) {
                 /**I want to refresh DIV likes after this **/
            } else {
                 $("#likes").addClass("red"); //This is working fine, i get message when already liked
           }
      }
  });
}
```

**likes.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST)) {
     //All PHP staff goes here and its working
     if ( $success) {
         $return = array (
               'code' = 0,
               'message' = ""
               );
     } else {
         $return["code"] = 1;
         $return["message"] = "You already liked";
     }
     echo json_encode($return);//Converting PHP into JSON format
}
?>
```

Comment: refresh means, you want to update the count for like??

Comment: You need to fetch and return data from the table in your ajax call, then just update the div with the new likes.

Answer (score 1):

change following in HTML and JS

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like" onclick="return like(<?php echo $_SESSION["id"];?>);"/>



<script>
function like(id1) {

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "likes.php",
    data: {id: id1 },
    success: function(feedback) {

        var _js = jQuery.parseJSON(feedback); 

        $("#likes").html(_js.message);  //printing message here 
        $("#likes").attr("class", ""); //resetting class of CSS

        if( _js.code == 0) {
             /**I want to refresh DIV likes after this **/
        } else {
             $("#likes").addClass("red"); //This is working fine, i get message when already liked
       }
  }
});
return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@tashi,

There is a syntax error in likes.php. Use `=>` operator when declaring arrays. The code should be as follows.

```
$return = array (
  'code' => 0,
  'message' => ""
);
```

Comment: Pradeep, I am sorry I didn't mention codes are working fine. These are simplied version. Which I wrote. After likes updated in Database, how can I refresh DIV likes with updated one?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display no of likes on success the change your code as follows

In likes.php

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST)) {
     //All PHP staff goes here and its working
     if ( $success) {
         $return = array (
               'code' => 0,
               'message' => "",
               'likes_count' => $likes_count //get updated likes count from db
               );
     } else {
         $return["code"] = 1;
         $return["message"] = "You already liked";
         //here you do not need to send the like count
     }
     echo json_encode($return);//Converting PHP into JSON format
}
?>
```

javascript code

```
function like(id1) {

    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likes.php",
        data: {id: id1 },
        success: function(feedback) {

            var _js = jQuery.parseJSON(feedback); 

            $("#likes").html(_js.message);  //printing message here 
            $("#likes").attr("class", ""); //resetting class of CSS

            if( _js.code == 0) {
                 /**I want to refresh DIV likes after this **/
                 $('#likes').html(_js.likes_count);//this will update your likes count
            } else {
                 $("#likes").addClass("red"); //This is working fine, i get message when already liked
           }
      }
  });
}
```